# Instrument cluster display not switching on in c220 d Benz

Tags: mercedes-benz, instrument-cluster, instrument

Instrumental cluster not getting on in the Mercedes c220 d 2016 model any help ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Center display is working fine , but the instrumental cluster is not getting on but everything else is working fine

Comment: Are you saying the gauges aren't working, but the lights show up? Which part of the instrument cluster isn't working?

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of follow up.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the instrument cluster lights there's a dimmer dial right next to the headlight knob, it's easy to accidentally turn the lights all the way down by mistake. Try turning it up and see if that fixes the problem.